# How do i update Google Cloud Function source?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've used this command to deploy a function from local source:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloWorld --trigger-http
```

Now, i have updated it's code. How do i deploy my changes?

When i'm using the same command, it returns status success with some details, but the deployed function remains intact (it uses the very first version of deployed code).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am running into the same issue. I've deployed my original HTTP function, updated the source, and am now trying to redeploy.

This could perhaps be a bug in the gcloud CLI, but I was able to successfully redeploy from my local machine by leveraging the `--source` command line flag. Be sure to point this flag to the **directory** containing your index.js.

`gcloud beta functions deploy helloWorld --source=/usr/local/path/to/source/dir --http-trigger`

Where index.js would be located at `/usr/local/path/to/source/dir/index.js`. Further CLI documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy.

Comment: If you're running that command from the local source directory, you can use: `gcloud beta functions deploy helloWorld --source=. --http-trigger`

Answer (score 7):

Providing an updated answer for anyone that needs it. If you are wanting to just redeploy a function from source the following works assuming you are in the directory of the index.js file. And to clarify this is to redeploy to a gcp function that already exists, not a new one.

```
gcloud functions deploy <FUNCTION_NAME> --source=.
```

Comment: It seems like if your original function had additional arguments, you'll still have to include them. So  redeploying the OP's function with other args would look like:
`gcloud functions deploy <FUNCTION_NAME> --source=. --trigger-http
<...ADDITIONAL ARGS>`

Answer (score 0):

Note to anyone coming across this thread and finding it not working for them.

If you deployed your function with gen2 then you need to specify theat in the command or else gcloud will think that you're trying to create a new function and it will fail in the end (because you already have a function with the same name)

So if you deployed using gen2...your deploy command should be:

```
gcloud functions deploy <FUNCTION_NAME> --gen2 --project=freemius-related
```

This is if you're running the command from inside the root directory on your local machine. If you're running the command from outside the root directory of your function, then you can use `--source=<path>` to specify where the command should pull the source code from.